# How to generate only data script from a backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, smo

I have been trying to generate only data script for specific `Tables` using `SMO` from a `backup` but with no success.

Is there a way to do so ? (even with without `SMO`)

Conditions : 

 - Data script generation has to be done programatically so I can give tables list as a parameter.

 - Data script generation has to respect tables dependency (FKs constraints).